# Java: Extending a class and adding a no-arg constructor (for wrapper)

Tags: java, class, javafx, constructor, extend

I need to extend a class *ChartViewer*, which does not have a no-arg constructor,  with a class *ChartViewerWrapper* to add a no-arg constructor.

How would I go about doing this?

---

**Extra information (not that relevant)**

The reason I need to do this is as a workaround as per below, the quote is taken from a forum regarding JavaFX 8 and JFreeChart. I want to use *ChartViewer* in FXML:

> Currently the ChartViewer node cannot be used in FXML. I think the
>   only reason is because it does not have a constructor without
>   arguments (when I extended the ChartViewer class and added a simple
>   constructor without arguments, I could add my wrapper class into FXML
>   and it works).

(I could just add a no-arg constructor directly in *ChartViewer*, but it is an External Library and for various good reasons I decided I don't want to do this.)

Comment: I guess you just need a way to provide arguments to ChartViewer's  constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Scary Wombat answered the general question I had, this is a solution for my particular case:

```
public class ChartViewerWrapper extends ChartViewer {

    public ChartViewerWrapper() {
        super(new JFreeChart(new XYPlot())); // just an empty placeholder...
    }

}
```

Then you can use *ChartViewerWrapper* in FXML, for example like so:

```
<Pane>
    <ChartViewerWrapper />
</Pane>
```

And change the associated properties in the controller when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

provide a no-arg constructor in `ChartViewerWrapper` and on its first line call

```
super (arg1, arg2);
```

assuming that `ChartViewer` has two parameters

- sorry I d not know what `ChartViewer`'s real constructor looks like

Comment: Thanks, this answered the general question and helped me solve it. I posted the more detailed solution as an answer.